# Documentation for newest google speech api in c#

Tags: speech-to-text, google-api-dotnet-client

yesterday I installed the Google.Apis.Speech.v1beta1 Client Library using the package manager in visual studio as indicated in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Speech.v1beta1/1.32.2.1132, I get there from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started, but all documentation and samples I've found so far are for Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 anyone can point to documentation or samples for the new library? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Google.Cloud.Speech.V1? The Google.Cloud.* packages are were most of our engineering and documentation efforts are now going. As far as I know there are no specific samples for the older Google.Apis.Speech.v1beta1

Comment: it was the one that I found in the nuget packages list, don't know how to install the cloud version, I'm just following the documentation that I find.

Comment: thanks for pointing that the developers documentation link to the old libraries list, now I've installed the cloud package.

Comment: Glad to hear you're trying Google.Cloud.Speech.V1